# Eclipse adds * to comment blocks

Tags: eclipse

After adding /*  and */ to a chunk of code in eclipse, and after saving, the editor adds * before each line, which eventually transforms this:

```
/*
line_of_code1
line_of_code2
line_of_code3
*/
```

to this:

```
/*
 *  line_of_code1
 *  line_of_code2
 *  line_of_code3
 */
```

I realy want to avoid it because after decommenting I need to delete each * by hand.
What save action or formatter action is this and how can I disable it?

Thank you.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @me 1982 All these answers given are completely true if you are using eclipse for java.

Comment: You are right. I am using Eclipse for Java

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `Ctrl+Shift+C` (or `Ctrl+ /`) for line comments or `Ctrl+Shift+/` for block comments (It will toggle, too). Eclipse by default does not add those asterisks.

The adding of asterisks typically only happens for /**, such as when writing javadoc. Are you sure you're not using double asterisk?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse for Java does this only if you use /** , instead of /*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment a piece of code temporarily, you can use the shortcut **Ctrl + /** on a selection of lines. This works in toggle mode, so you will be able to add and remove the comments quite fast.